# How to Test Complex Functions in NestJS?

Tags: unit-testing, mongoose, nestjs

I am currently testing my repository implementation in NestJS, and there have been a few challenges in creating tests for the repository. Here is a high-level view of the implementation:

1. There is a **MongoDBRepository** abstract class that contains common methods that can be used across different repositories.

```js
export abstract class MongoDbRepository<
  SchemaClass,
  CreateDto = RecursivePartial<SchemaClass>,
  UpdateDto = Extendable<CreateDto> | UpdateQuery<SchemaClass>,
> {
  constructor(protected readonly model: Model<SchemaClass>) {}
  ...
}
```

2. The system-under-test(SUT) is TestRepository, which extends MongoDBRepository

```js
@Injectable()
export class TestRepository extends MongoDbRepository<
  TaskConfigDoc,
  CreateTaskConfigRepoDto
> {...}
```

3. I'm currently testing **find** operations within TestRepository, which is implemented as below:

```js
@Injectable()
export class TestRepository extends MongoDbRepository<
  TestDoc,
  CreateTaskConfigRepoDto
> {
 ...
 async find(dto: FindTaskConfigsDto) {
    const filterQuery = this.refineQueryParams(dto);
    return this.findAllDocuments(filterQuery, this.buildQueryOptions);
  }
}
```

4. **findAllDocuments** is implemented in MongoDBRepository as shown below:

```js
type MongooseQuery<SchemaClass, ResultType = unknown> = Query<
  ResultType,
  HydratedDocument<SchemaClass>
>;

export abstract class MongoDbRepository<
  SchemaClass,
  CreateDto = RecursivePartial<SchemaClass>,
  UpdateDto = Extendable<CreateDto> | UpdateQuery<SchemaClass>,
> {
  constructor(protected readonly model: Model<SchemaClass>) {}

  async findAllDocuments(
    dto: FilterQueryDto & Record<string, any>,
    queryOptions: InternalQueryOptions,
    projection?: ProjectionFields<SchemaClass>,
  ): Promise<SchemaClass[]> {
    const filterQuery = this.refineFilterQuery(dto, queryOptions);
    const mongooseFindQuery = this.model.find(filterQuery, projection);
    return this.applyQueryOptions(mongooseFindQuery, dto, queryOptions).exec();
  }

  applyQueryOptions<ResultType = unknown>(
    query: MongooseQuery<SchemaClass, ResultType>,
    dto: FilterQueryDto,
    { maxTimeMs = 5000 }: InternalQueryOptions,
  ) {
    ...
    const updatedQuery = query
      .select(select)
      .skip(skip)
      .limit(limit)
      .sort(sort)
      .populate(populate)
      .maxTimeMS(maxTimeMs);

    return lean === true
      ? updatedQuery.lean<ResultType>({ virtuals: true, getters: true })
      : updatedQuery;
    }
}
```

5. This is my attempt to testing the **find** operation:

```js
describe('TestRepository', () => {
  let testRepository: TestRepository;

  describe('find operations', () => {
    let testFilterQuery: FilterQuery<TestDoc>;

    beforeEach(async () => {
      const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
        imports: [
          ...
          MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
            connectionName: 'TEST-V2',
            imports: [ConfigModule],
            inject: [ConfigService],
            useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
              uri: configService.get('db.mongo.testv2'),
            }),
          }),
        ],
        providers: [
          TestRepository,
          {
            provide: getConnectionToken('TEST-V2'),
            useValue: {},
          },
        ],
      }).compile();

      testRepository =
        moduleRef.get<TestRepository>(TestRepository);

      jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    describe('find', () => {
      describe('when find is called', () => {
        let tests: Test[];

        beforeEach(async () => {
          jest
            .spyOn(testRepository, 'applyQueryOptions')
            .mockReturnValue(testStub());
          tests = await testRepository.find({});
        });

        test('then it should call MongoDBRepository', () => {
          expect(test.findAllDocuments).toHaveBeenCalledWith({}, {});
        });

        test('then it should return task config', () => {
          expect(test).toEqual([testStub()]);
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The problem I'm experiencing is having to mock implement **applyQueryOptions**.  When the tests execute, I get the following error:
[image]

So my idea was to make use of `jest.spyOn` to spy on `applyQueryOptions` and mock the implementation or return value, as shown in step 5.  But, it seems to be a bit complicated because of the complex types.  Basically want I want is for **applyQueryOptions** to return an array of objects, but I get the error:

```
Argument of type 'Test' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Query<unknown, Test & Document<any, any, any> & { _id: any; }, {}, TaskConfig & Document<any, any, any> & { _id: any; }>'.
  Type 'Test' is missing the following properties from type 'Query<unknown, Test & Document<any, any, any> & { _id: any; }, {}, Test & Document<any, any, any> & { _id: any; }>': _mongooseOptions, exec, $where, all, and 93 more
```

Is there anyway for me to just easily mock **applyQueryOptions** to just return an array of objects?